# sql server 2005 trigger after delete

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, triggers, sql-delete

I have written a trigger on a table after delete row to update some other table using a field from the 'deleted' (magic table). It works fine for single row delete.
But when I try to do deletes like

```sql
delete from tblIndentDetails 
WHERE indentID=5;
```

(it is supposed to delete more than one records meeting the criterion), the delete operation is not performed due to trigger. How can I work around the situation?

Comment: Is it when you "manually" (with your sql query) try to delete more than one row, from the table that has the trigger, that the same delete is not performed (rolled back)? Do you get an error? What does the trigger code look like?

Comment: We will need to the the SQL code for your trigger.